# Query SQL API in CosmosDB using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Query SQL API in CosmosDB using C# :

My requirement is to query jsonData from CosmosDB (SQL API). The Below code is doing that work but it is taking 5-6 seconds to execute and return the Data.

```
            using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosAccountEndpoint))
            {
                
                var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = //our id";

                QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);

                FeedIterator<dynamic> queryResultSetIterator = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseName).GetContainer(containerName).GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(queryDefinition);
                
                FeedResponse<dynamic> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync(); //this Line itself is taking 4-5 seconds time

                result = currentResultSet.Resource.ToList().FirstOrDefault(); //this line taking out the required response.
            }
```

As an alternative, I'm trying out the below (its not working). In below code, CollectionUri is not getting loaded properly and thrwoing System.InvalidOperationException.

```
                using (var client = new DocumentClient("uri", "key", new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionMode.Gateway, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp, RetryOptions = retryOptions }))
                {
                    var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = //our id";
                    Uri collectionUri = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, containerName);
                    CustomersInfo = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collectionUri, new SqlQuerySpec() {QueryText = sqlQueryText,Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection() { } }, DefaultOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
                };
```

Is there any alternative to the first code OR any changes to be made in second code to work.......

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you querying for a single item?

The reason why it's so slow is because this is a cross partition query.

Rewrite this as a point read, ie. ReadItemAsync() and pass in the partition key value and this will execute much faster.

Also, if this is a new application I recommend using the v3 .NET SDK rather than the v2 SDK. This is very old and is not getting any new enhancements.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. Yes I'm querying for a single item. But the Query is based on (id and timestamp of the record). And when I use ReadItemAsync()-> I'm ending up getting this exception:  ' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid.

Comment: And also, I guess we cannot have a complex query with ReadItemAsync().

Comment: I've never seen that error before. If you have the id why do you need the timestamp? Can you show your code for how you are doing ReadItemAsync(). You only need the id and the partition key value to do a point read in Cosmos.

Comment: using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosAccountEndpoint))
                    {

                        ItemResponse<dynamic> queryResultSetIterator = await cosmosClient.GetDatabase("databaseName").GetContainer("containerName").ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, new PartitionKey("/key"));
                     

                        return queryResultSetIterator.Resource;
                    }

Comment: Attached the code in Comments. And I need to consider timestamp to check whether the record is latest or not.

Comment: You are not calling ReadItemAsync correctly. You need to pass in the partition key value, not the path in this method.

Comment: Hi Mark, yeah if I pass the partition key value, able to get the response. And Can we filter it based on timeStamp along with id...(I wanted to retrieve the latest Data only as per requirement)